# IMG src two images align to div center

Tags: css

```
<div class="box">
        <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/c5lw89577/Untitled_2.jpg" />
        <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/c5lw89577/Untitled_2.jpg" />
        <p>
            uspendisse potenti. Ut id justo libero, in bibes 
        </p>
  </div>
```

**[jsfiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/CjZSS/)**

How to make images src align to center. the result I'd like to get is to like the picture below. ideally works on IE7 and IE8 as well

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HTML `<img>` elements are inline level elements, so they are affected by the `text-align` property.

Paragraphs are block level elements, so they won't wrap around the images unless you use CSS to change that. All you need is this: ( http://jsfiddle.net/7sKeA/ )

```
.box {
    width:600px;
    text-align:center;
}
img {
    margin:5px;
}
```

If you then also need the `.box` to remain centered, target it with a `margin:auto;` like so: ( http://jsfiddle.net/7sKeA/1/ )

```
.box {
    width:600px;
    text-align:center; /* center align the text inside the box */
    margin:auto; /* center this .box element, assuming it is block-level */
}
img {
    margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: Nice simplification and description of what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

Put them inside of a centered block element.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/c5lw89577/Untitled_2.jpg" />
    <img src="http://s21.postimg.org/c5lw89577/Untitled_2.jpg" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/CjZSS/2/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest giving the images a container div and applying `text-align:center` to that div.
Also, remove `display:block` from the images to keep them on one line.

```
div.images {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CjZSS/3/

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problem in the past and this -
`<p align=center><img src="img/test.jpg"></p>`
worked for me.

Comment: I believe the `align` attribute has been depreciated in favor of CSS style sheets. http://fantasai.tripod.com/qref/HTML4/deprecated.html